Why do I get Highcharts undefined?
I've been using this library for almost a year on several projects and yesterday it was working perfectly as usual but today I'm getting the error on all projects:
Uncaught ReferenceError: Highcharts is not defined
I'm using vanilla JavaScript, HTML and CSS and I imported the CDN on the HTML head tag because that's how I work.
I tried using Highcharts GTP and tested a simple code to make sure the CDN worked but I got the same error in my local testing. This is the code that de AI provided me:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Stock Chart Example</title>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="container" style="height: 400px; min-width: 310px"></div>
    <script>
      document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
        Highcharts.stockChart("container", {
          rangeSelector: {
            selected: 1,
          },
          title: {
            text: "AAPL Stock Price",
          },
          series: [
            {
              name: "AAPL",
              data: [
                [Date.UTC(2021, 0, 1), 132.43],
                [Date.UTC(2021, 1, 1), 126.6],
                [Date.UTC(2021, 2, 1), 123.9],
                [Date.UTC(2021, 3, 1), 134.16],
                [Date.UTC(2021, 4, 1), 127.79],
                [Date.UTC(2021, 5, 1), 139.91],
                [Date.UTC(2021, 6, 1), 145.11],
                [Date.UTC(2021, 7, 1), 156.3],
                [Date.UTC(2021, 8, 1), 145.0],
                [Date.UTC(2021, 9, 1), 149.55],
                [Date.UTC(2021, 10, 1), 161.0],
                [Date.UTC(2021, 11, 1), 177.57],
              ],
              tooltip: {
                valueDecimals: 2,
              },
            },
          ],
        });
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>



Does the resource get loaded? Sounds like probably isn't and you should have some sort of network error about it.

no bro you are not alone. I am working with the same library and same problem

If you happen to find the older version of the library, let me know. I am looking for one right now.

I was reading some comments about the new version (HIGHCHARTS V12) and people are getting a lot of problems.

This is the risk of always using the latest version which can be updated at any point without testing and is why many people (including myself) advocate not relying on whatever the latest version is and  always testing updated versions when upgrading. You should specify the specific version you want when using the highcharts CDN (or any other hosted scripts). Doing this you shouldn't be surprised by any "broken" updates to libraries your application depends upon.
Taking a quick look at the Highcharts CDN reveals that the current version (as of 20/12/2024) is 12.1.1 and was released today with the previous version, 12.1.0, being released on 17/12/2024.
Try updating your script tag to explicitly use this previous version:
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/12.1.0/highstock.js"></script>

UPDATE
Although I wouldn't expect any breaking changes by a bug release, by taking the latest version you are always going to be at risk from breaking changes between major versions.

you dropped this

@MikeLennon Thank you

Thanks! @phuzi. I was not aware about broken releases.

This was it... but damn!  Updating from version 4.x to 12.x and end up banging my head wondering why the latest version is coming up as undefined.  It made NO sense... sigh

Issue fixed: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/22423

UPDATE
Issue has already been fixed, the error came from trying to access document.body before it was defined. It happens when loading Highcharts v12.1.1 from the head section of the page. Unfortunately all our tests, samples and demos load Highcharts from the body, so we didn't pick up this issue. Fix is already there with v12.1.2.

no it's the library version. it got updated today. it was not tested properly. switching to 12.1.0 from 12.1.1 is the current best solution.

Version 12.0.0 was released back in November and is unlikely to be the culprit since users are reporting that it broke today coinciding with the 12.1.1 release

I've tested the code on the newest version explicitly; it works well: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/L7h6by9d/
We have noticed similar issues with rendering from the release of v12.0.0, and 99% were caused by the cache isssues.

I have the same problem using the newest version from today, 12.1.1. 12.1.0 works without problems.
It seems to be related to detecting the language of the page:
highcharts.js:8 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'closest')
    at highcharts.js:8:898
    at highcharts.js:8:1778
    at highcharts.js:9:272787
    at highcharts.js:8:324
    at highcharts.js:8:329

This is this line in the highcharts code:
   t.pageLang = t.doc?.body.closest("[lang]")?.lang,

Updating production code on a friday is risky.. and now just before the Christmas holidays.

I don't have enough reps to comment. But clearing the cache did not work for me. Using the main CDN also generates Highcharts undefined. Using this:
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highstock.js"></script> instead of <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/12.1.1/highstock.js"></script>
breaks the above fiddle. This chart runs on the website but not in the fiddle. There is also a similar situation with Highmaps.
